# What does the "weights" do in mgcv:gam? And how to put weights in gam?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv, weights

In generalized linear model we can put weights so that glm function can work faster. However for generalized additive models, in `mgcv:gam` we also can put `weights`. But I'm not sure whether this works in the similar way! Or how does it work? Or if it doesn’t work in that way then what is the procedure for putting weighs in GAM?

Comment: Do you have any reference about 'weights make glm faster' ? weights come from the design or they may be used to correct for heteroscedasticity, efficiency in estimation but I have never seen using them to enhance computational efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

`weights` works in the same way for `gam()` and it does for `glm()` - GAMs fitted by `gam()` and `bam()` are really just fancy GLMs, and when the models contain smooths then they are fitted with a penalised version of the algorithm used to fit GLMs.

Because changing the weights changes the overall magnitude of the likelihood. You will likely want to actually used `weights = my_weights / mean(my_weights)`, which is given on the help page for `?gam` in the description of the `weights` argument.

I wouldn't recommend using bootstrapping with GAMs however; non-parametric bootstrapping can lead to over smoothing because of the repeated observations of some samples in each bootstrap sample, and parametric bootstrapping of models is incredibly time consuming for GAMs and we can usually do just as well with posterior simulation.